# Nikon D3200 with IR remote control uses AF-Light although turned off

Tags: remote, nikon-d3200, focus-assist

I have big issue on my Nikon D3200: If I use an IR remote control, the AF-Assist Light always flashes, *after* taking a photo, although I explicitly disabled it in the menu!

How can I disable it completely?

Comment: If the light is causing a problem you could get a small piece of thick black tape like plumbers' tape and tape over

Comment: The information is on page 25 in the book you get and on page 33 of the downloadable pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to page 33 of the [D3200 Reference Manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D3200_EN.pdf), the light you see is functioning as the *self-timer lamp*, not as the *AF-assist illuminator*. The manual includes no instructions as to how this feature might be disabled.

One possible workaround might be to use an [MC-DC2 Remote Release Cord (1 Meter)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F6TXME) wired cable release instead of the wireless remote.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. (Sorry, you're correct - it isn't the AF Light, but anyway it's should to be disable by the menu/firmware)

Comment: Just put a bit of tape over it